# How many desktop environments are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10

How many are the Desktop environments provided and supported by Ubuntu?

Comment: this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome, KDE, LXDE, Xfce and, I think rox. Those are desktop environments. Then you have many window managers and shells that can be used with these DEs. I guess about twenty shells and 5-10 window managers or something.

Comment: Way more than 10 wm's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager#X_Window_managers I would expect most of these to be on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

gnome, kde, lxde,openbox xfce i can't remember more.

Comment: Don't forget Unity!  It counts, too!

Comment: No, it doesn't. Unity is not a desktop environment. It is a shell. OpenBox is not a desktop environment either, though. It is a window manager.